# Ada: accessing a record variable

Tags: record, ada

Hi I am making a program to calculate vector components. Since 2D vectors have a *horizontal* and a *vertical* component in the Cartesian space, I have decided to use the **record** construction.

The program first calculates the basis vector and this is what is shown below. The  *horizontal*, *vertical* components as well as an *angle* is asked as input. The *angle* refers to the anticlockwise positive angle from the default Cartesian coordinate system to another rotated Cartesian coordinate system from the original one.

In the file `Projections.adb` you will see the calculation:

```
D.Horz := A * Cos (C);
```

where `A` is the *horizontal* component of the original Cartesian coordinate system and `C` is the angle that denotes the rotation between the new Cartesian coordinate system and the old system.

In the *main* program `Get_projections.adb`, the calling **procedure** is

```
Vector_basis_r (Component_Horz, Component_Vert, theta, Basis_r);
```

`Ada` complains when I issue the command:

```
Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Basis_r.Horz, Fore => 3, Aft  => 3, Exp  => 0);
```

when I want to retrieve the *horizontal* component of the basis vector.

The complaint is:

*invalid prefix in selected component "Basis_r"*.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

The necessary files are down here:

The **main** file is `Get_Projections.adb`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Projections; Use Projections;
with Ada.Numerics.Long_Elementary_Functions;
use Ada.Numerics.Long_Elementary_Functions;


procedure Get_Projections is

   Component_Horz, Component_Vert, theta  : Long_Float;
   Basis_r                                : Rectangular;

begin

  Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the horizontal component ");
  Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Component_Horz);
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
  Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the vertical component ");
  Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Component_Vert);
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
  Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the angle ");
  Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => theta);

  Vector_basis_r (Component_Horz, Component_Vert, theta, Basis_r);


  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  Ada.Text_IO.Put("rx = ");
  Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Basis_r.Horz, Fore => 3, Aft  => 3, Exp  => 0);

end Get_Projections;
```

and the **accompanying** packages are the specification `Projections.ads`:

```
package Projections is

   type Rectangular is private;
   procedure Vector_basis_r (A, B, C : in Long_Float; D : out Rectangular);

private
   type Rectangular is
        record
             Horz, Vert: Long_Float;
        end record;

end Projections;
```

and the package body `Projections.adb`:

```
with Ada.Numerics.Long_Elementary_Functions;
use  Ada.Numerics.Long_Elementary_Functions;

package body Projections is

   procedure Vector_basis_r (A, B, C : in Long_Float; D : out Rectangular) is
   begin
      D.Horz := A * Cos (C);
      D.Vert := B * Sin (c);
   end Vector_basis_r;

end Projections;
```

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rectangular is a private type, therefore other packages do not have access to its components, Horz (or Vert) in this case.  The fields of the Rectangular type can only be accessed by Projections' package body, or in the private part or bodies of any child packages of Projections.

Either place the Rectangular type declaration in the public part of package Projections, or provide Get/Set accessors to interact with the record's components.

Comment: @ Marc C Thank you very much indeed. I have simply taken away the `private` part. If I would have to provide *Get/Set accessors to interact with the record's components*, how to go about? Can you please show an example? 1 vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan  By "Get/Set accessors" I mean nothing more than functions that take a Rectangle parameter and access its members. E.g. "function Get_Horz(R : Rectangle) return Long_Float;" and a "procedure Set_Horz(R : in out Rectangle; H : Long_Float);"

Comment: @ Marc C Thanks. I am quite new to this. I can write a function in the `adb` file as function Get_Horz (R : Rectangular) return Long_Float is
   begin
      return R.Horz;
   end Get_Horz;. This part is OK: I do not understand the `procedure Set_Horz...`. Could you please write it full for me? Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @yCalleecharan   procedure Set_Horz(R : in out Rectangle; H : Long_Float) is begin R.Horz := H; end Set_Horz;

Comment: @ Marc C. Ok, then how to output the variable say the horizontal component using `Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put`?

Comment: @ Marc C. Ok I figured out this one. It should be `Get_Horz(Basis_r)`. Thanks for walking me through...

Answer (score 2):

I would put a `put` procedure in the projections package:

```
package Projections is

   type Rectangular is private;
   procedure Vector_basis_r (A, B, C : in Long_Float; D : out Rectangular);

   procedure put (r : in Rectangular);

private
   type Rectangular is
        record
             Horz, Vert: Long_Float;
        end record;

end Projections;
```

Then your privates stay hidden and you can print them with impunity.

```
put (basis_r);
```

and have as the body of the put:

```
procedure put (r : in Rectangular) is
begin 
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  Ada.Text_IO.Put("rx = ");
  Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => r.Horz, Fore => 3, Aft  => 3, Exp  => 0);
end put;
```

Comment: @ NWS Excellent alternative and thanks. I have placed the body of the `put` procedure in the file `Projections.adb`. It works fine. 1 vote up.

Comment: Put really ought to take an additional `Ada.Text_IO.File_Type` parameter (if not `Fore`, `Aft` and `Exp`).

Comment: @SimonWright - Correct if you were trying to emulate the defined put methods (Which i was not!), perhaps my put should be renamed print_horizontal to be more accurate.